# Embedded C# bitpacked arrays to low-level STM32F4 driver for GE G35 RGB LED Christmas tree light

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise, embedded, device-driver

I'm going to be opensourcing some code I'm working on.  I don't need help with the code, I just want to make sure my code is readable and my comments make sense.  I have a knack for the esoteric.  This code is to control GE G35 Christmas lights using a Netduino controller. Due to the .NET overhead, I've written a custom lower-level driver compiled into the firmware.

Can you follow my code? This is on an embedded processor which is why I'm doing a lot of bit-shifting. It's easier to write this way.

```
   public Int32[,] getData()
    {
        int maxBulbs = getMaxBulbs();

        // Using an abdnormal form of bitpacking here to make the C loop, very tight and efficient.
        // The first address of the array is the bulb position on all strings.
        // The second address of the array is actually the corresponding bulb information for that bit.
        // Within the array, we store a 32-bit int. Each bit in this int, represents a G35 Strand/string
        // So at data[0, 0] we have a 32 bit int, this int represents the first bulb on all strings, first data information bit for up to 32 strands.
        Int32[,] data = new Int32[getMaxBulbs(), 26]; // number bulbs on a strand, 26 bit bulb info

        foreach (G35String gstring in Strings)
        {
            for (short c_bulb = 1; c_bulb < maxBulbs; c_bulb++)
            {
                // This is a bit of a shortcut. because we know that G35's just pass the information down
                // the pipe and due to the way we are sending data in parallel, if one string has
                // more bulbs than another, we just send fake data to the non existent bulb on that string
                G35Bulb gbulb = (c_bulb < gstring.bulbs.Length ? gstring.bulbs[c_bulb] : new G35Bulb(0, 0));

                // bulb address
                data[c_bulb, 0] = (c_bulb & 0x20) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 1] = (c_bulb & 0x10) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 2] = (c_bulb & 0x08) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 3] = (c_bulb & 0x04) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 4] = (c_bulb & 0x02) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 5] = (c_bulb & 0x01) << gstring.StringPinAddress;

                // bulb brightness
                data[c_bulb, 6] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x80) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 7] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x40) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 8] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x20) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 9] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x10) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 10] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x08) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 11] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x04) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 12] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x02) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 13] = (gbulb.BulbBrightness & 0x01) << gstring.StringPinAddress;

                // Blue
                data[c_bulb, 14] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x8) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 15] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x4) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 16] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x2) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 17] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x1) << gstring.StringPinAddress;

                // Green
                data[c_bulb, 18] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x8) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 19] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x4) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 20] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x2) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 21] = (gbulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x1) << gstring.StringPinAddress;

                // Red
                data[c_bulb, 22] = (gbulb.BulbColor & 0x8) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 23] = (gbulb.BulbColor & 0x4) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 24] = (gbulb.BulbColor & 0x2) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
                data[c_bulb, 25] = (gbulb.BulbColor & 0x1) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

In the C++ driver, I can blast all the registers I need like this in parallel:

```
// LED Address
sendBits(data[i][0]);
sendBits(data[i][1]);
sendBits(data[i][2]);
sendBits(data[i][3]);
sendBits(data[i][4]);
sendBits(data[i][5]);

void sendBits(uint16_t gpioPins, uint32_t data)
{
    *_BSRRL = gpioPins;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRH = gpioPins;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRL = ~data;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRL = gpioPins;
}
```

Comment: Very cool project. Please come back and share the repo when you open source it. =)

Answer (score 7):

1. Standard C# naming convention for methods is `PascalCase`. Following standard naming conventions makes the code look more familiar to other C# developers (which might be important as you plan to open source it)
2. You are potentially wasting some cycles here by calling `getMaxBulbs()` again even though you just did it and have the result stored in `maxBulbs`:

   > ```
   > Int32[,] data = new Int32[getMaxBulbs(), 26];
   > ```
3. `c_bulb` is not a very nice name. `bulbIndex` would have been better.
4. `gbulb` should probably just be `bulb` as it represents a bulb object.
5. Rather than using the somewhat generic names of `Strings` for a string of bulbs maybe `BulbString` would be better.
6. I might be missing something but your outer loop which loops over `Strings` constantly overwrites the content of `data` and only the values from the last iteration will actually be in there due to the assignment operator. Did you mean to write:

   ```
   data[c_bulb, 0] |= (c_bulb & 0x20) << gstring.StringPinAddress;
   ```

   instead (OR-ing the bit masks)?

Comment: Chris, all great suggestions that I've incorporated. I edited the above post.  And great catch on the OR!

Comment: @MichaelRice: Could you please roll back the changes to your question? See [this question on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Comment: All fixed. Added your suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the new code with @ChrisWue's suggestions.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SPOT;

namespace Netduino.G35.Main
{
public class G35Cluster
{
    public G35String[] BulbStrings;

    public int getMaxBulbs()
    {
        int maxBulbs = 0;

        foreach (G35String bulbString in BulbStrings)
        {
            maxBulbs = (maxBulbs > bulbString.Bulbs.Length ? bulbString.Bulbs.Length : maxBulbs) + 1; // we add 1 to keep the bulb addressing below simple
        }

        return maxBulbs;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        UInt32 gpioPins = 0;
        foreach (G35String gstring in this.BulbStrings)
        {
            // This uses the OR equals operator to flip the pin address bit.
            // This will tell the low-level driver which pins it can flip to
            // high or low for pin state management
            // So if for some reason, you had G35 strings on GPIO pins 1, 4, 8
            // Then the binary of this would look like, B00000000000000000000000010001001
            gpioPins |= (UInt32)(1 << gstring.StringPinAddress);
        }
    }

    public Int32[,] getData()
    {
        int maxBulbs = getMaxBulbs();

        // Using an abdnormal form of bitpacking here to make the C loop, very tight and efficient.
        // The first address of the array is the bulb position on all strings.
        // The second address of the array is actually the corresponding bulb information for that bit.
        // Within the array, we store a 32-bit int. Each bit in this int, represents a G35 Strand/string
        // So at data[0, 0] we have a 32 bit int, this int represents the first bulb on all strings, first data information bit for up to 32 strands.
        Int32[,] data = new Int32[maxBulbs, 26]; // number bulbs on a strand, 26 bit bulb info

        foreach (G35String bulbString in BulbStrings)
        {
            for (short bulbIndex = 1; bulbIndex < maxBulbs; bulbIndex++)
            {
                // This is a bit of a shortcut. because we know that G35's just pass the information down
                // the pipe and due to the way we are sending data in parallel, if one string has
                // more bulbs than another, we just send fake data to the non existent bulb on that string
                G35Bulb bulb = (bulbIndex < bulbString.Bulbs.Length ? bulbString.Bulbs[bulbIndex] : new G35Bulb(0, 0));

                // bulb address
                data[bulbIndex, 0] |= (bulbIndex & 0x20) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 1] |= (bulbIndex & 0x10) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 2] |= (bulbIndex & 0x08) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 3] |= (bulbIndex & 0x04) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 4] |= (bulbIndex & 0x02) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 5] |= (bulbIndex & 0x01) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;

                // bulb brightness
                data[bulbIndex, 6] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x80) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 7] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x40) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 8] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x20) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 9] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x10) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 10] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x08) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 11] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x04) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 12] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x02) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 13] |= (bulb.BulbBrightness & 0x01) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;

                // Blue
                data[bulbIndex, 14] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x8) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 15] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x4) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 16] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x2) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 17] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 8 & 0x1) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;

                // Green
                data[bulbIndex, 18] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x8) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 19] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x4) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 20] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x2) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 21] |= (bulb.BulbColor >> 4 & 0x1) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;

                // Red
                data[bulbIndex, 22] |= (bulb.BulbColor & 0x8) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 23] |= (bulb.BulbColor & 0x4) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 24] |= (bulb.BulbColor & 0x2) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
                data[bulbIndex, 25] |= (bulb.BulbColor & 0x1) << bulbString.StringPinAddress;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
}
```

In the C++ driver, I can blast all the registers I need like this in parallel:

```
// LED Address
sendBits(data[i][0]);
sendBits(data[i][1]);
sendBits(data[i][2]);
sendBits(data[i][3]);
sendBits(data[i][4]);
sendBits(data[i][5]);

void sendBits(uint16_t gpioPins, uint32_t data)
{
    *_BSRRL = gpioPins;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRH = gpioPins;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRL = ~data;
    delayMicroseconds(DELAYSHORT); // 10us
    *_BSRRL = gpioPins;
}
```